# How to create an installer of a browser-based system?

Tags: installation, iexpress

I just developed a browser-based employee management system. I am wondering if there is a way for me to create an installer or a self-extracting file to transfer the system to another computer easily.

I have tried using "iexpress.exe" and "Actual Installer" however it seems they only extract in a single directory. Is there a way for me to specify which file should go to a specific directory using these applications? If none, any suggestions how to do it?

Comment: When you say "browser based" system, what exactly are you installing?

Answer (score 5):

You can make IExpress put files into subdirectories using [a technique described by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553615(v=vs.85).aspx#creating_a_command_line_script). In your *install program*, you’d need to do something similar to:

```
@md i386
@xcopy /q /y toastva.exe i386\.
@xcopy /q /y tostrcls.dll i386\.
@xcopy /q /y tostrco2.dll i386\.
@xcopy /q /y toaster.sys i386\.
```

(You could use `move /y` instead of `xcopy`, if that’s what you wanted to do.)

This is due to a technical limitation in the way IExpress generates its CAB file. IExpress generates a DDF file which is read by `makecab.exe`; this file places all source files in the same destination folder. Thus each source file must have a unique name, regardless of its source directory.

While `makecab.exe` itself supports subdirectories, the input DDF file is generated on-the-fly by IExpress, so it would be difficult (if not impossible) to intercept it and make changes before `makecab.exe` reads it.

---

But honestly, if you need subdirectories (and sub-subdirectories…) then you might want to consider using a "real" installer maker. Some examples in no particular order:

- [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)
- [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/)
- [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/)

Comment: This answer says it can be done using IExpress (albeit with limitations) but doesn't explain how. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I dunno, I'm feeling kind of demotivated by the downvote.

Comment: Ha, sorry for demotivating you. :-) Actually I see now the original question wasn't only about IExpress, so I'll remove the downvote and remotivate you. FWIW, I couldn't find any way to do it with IExpress, so I've switched to using 7zip.

Comment: But SO won't let me remove my downvote unless the answer gets edited, and I'm not motivated enough to edit it.

Comment: I’ve adjusted my answer. I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Upvote for accepting IExpress isn't really a suitable tool for 'real' installers.