# iexpress doesn't maintain folder structure when expanding to temp

Tags: iexpress

Environment: Windows 7 64, Visual Studio 2013

Prior to running iexpress I have a setup file that references a main msi, and a prerequisite msi (SlimDX).  When the visual studio installer adds the prerequisite, it adds places the prereq msi in a subfolder next to setup.exe.

Now I'm using iexpress.exe to merge the setup.exe and 2 msi files.  When iexpress extracts the 3 files to the temp folder, the redistributable is not in a subfolder despite the setup file still expecting it in a subfolder.

How can I force iexpress to maintain folder structure when extracting?  Alternatively, when adding a prerequisite to a visual studio installer, how can I force it to place dependencies at the same folder level as the setup.exe?

SDE file

```
[Version]
Class=IEXPRESS
SEDVersion=3
[Options]
PackagePurpose=InstallApp
ShowInstallProgramWindow=0
HideExtractAnimation=0
UseLongFileName=1
InsideCompressed=0
CAB_FixedSize=0
CAB_ResvCodeSigning=0
RebootMode=I
InstallPrompt=%InstallPrompt%
DisplayLicense=%DisplayLicense%
FinishMessage=%FinishMessage%
TargetName=%TargetName%
FriendlyName=%FriendlyName%
AppLaunched=%AppLaunched%
PostInstallCmd=%PostInstallCmd%
AdminQuietInstCmd=%AdminQuietInstCmd%
UserQuietInstCmd=%UserQuietInstCmd%
SourceFiles=SourceFiles
[Strings]
InstallPrompt=
DisplayLicense=
FinishMessage=
TargetName=C:\Jobs\NME\Installer\Release\NMEInstaller.EXE
FriendlyName=NME Installer
AppLaunched=setup.exe
PostInstallCmd=<None>
AdminQuietInstCmd=
UserQuietInstCmd=
FILE0="NME Installer.msi"
FILE1="setup.exe"
FILE2="SlimDXRedistributable\SlimDX Runtime .NET 4.0 x64 (January 2012).msi"
[SourceFiles]
SourceFiles0=C:\Jobs\NME\Installer\Release\
SourceFiles1=C:\Jobs\NME\Installer\Release\SlimDXRedistributable\
[SourceFiles0]
%FILE0%=
%FILE1%=
[SourceFiles1]
%FILE2%=
```

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that MSFT no longer recommends or supports the use of IEXpress.exe as it contains a number of security vulnerabilities that were never patched.  You really should consider switching over to a proper bootstrapper such as Windows Installer XML's Burn feature.  It's easier to implement and far more powerful.

Comment: While I don't at all disagree, do you have a reference for this?

Comment: http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2013/Oct/5

Comment: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Create-Single-installable-exe-td7596297.html

Comment: It’s not really much of a vulnerability – the one you linked wasn’t even accepted as such by Microsoft. It involves a version of IExpress from 2003/XP, not anything recent. (Again, I’ll stress that I don’t disagree about your recommendation to use something else, though.)

Comment: And by the way, in case you weren't aware, IExpress uses `CreateProcess`, which reads `cmd.exe` from `System32` before it even looks at `%path%`. Unless you somehow think you can predict exactly which directory a user runs the install package from, there’s really no way to inject a different `cmd.exe`. (And how would you even get it there?)

Answer (score 0):

I answered a question similar to this before:

- [How to create an installer of a browser-based system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847974/how-to-create-an-installer-of-a-browser-based-system/19055544#19055544)

Essentially you want to use a batch file (or something) to copy or move the files where you need them before executing the actual `setup.exe`, something like:

```
@echo off
mkdir SlimDXRedistributable
move /y "SlimDX Runtime .NET 4.0 x64 (January 2012).msi" SlimDXRedistributable
setup.exe
```

Remember if you're using a batch file to call it like:

```
cmd /c myscript.bat
```

(If you just put the batch file, it will run via the old `command.com`, which is suboptimal.)

Comment: you should vote to close or flag as a duplicate **not** re-answer the question